# Are there different here maps style css files?

Tags: here-api

Right now I am using the default maps ui: http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css.

But I am not completely happy with the black controle buttons (mapsetting, zoom).

On [js api start page](https://developer.here.com/develop/javascript-api) here maps is using white buttons without round corners, exactly what I want.

Is there a secound css file I did not found or will it be replace current black style in near future?

It is not the problem to change style by my own, but I would prefer a other way.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation - this is something you can specify when picking the map type (not entirely sure). Anyway, have a browse: https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics/map-types.html.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one CSS file with the black color scheme. My guess is, the developer.here.com color scheme is a custom override of the styles. But then again, the mapsjs-ui.css file uncompressed making your own color overrides relatively simple.

I agree that if they change CSS rules it's your issue. However, that doesn't seem to have happened, like... ever until now.